# Routing error No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"static_pages"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

i'm a ROR newbie who is going through the tutorial by Micheal Hartl. I have follow every steps of the tutorial and i'm stuck with the error regarding the routes. I have gone through all my codes and tried all the solution from google. Long story short i'm trying to get the test pass.

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'static_pages#home'
get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
end`
```

Here is the error description

> 1)Error 
>  StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:
>   ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"static_pages"} test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:10: in block in class:StaticPagesControllerTest'
>   
>  2) Error 
>  StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:
>   ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/help", :controller=>"static_pages"}
>   test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in class:StaticPagesControllerTest'

Here is how my rake routes looks like

> root GET  /                          static_pages#home
>   
> help GET  /help(.:format)        static_pages#help
>   
> about GET  /about(.:format)       static_pages#about
>   
> contact GET  /contact(.:format)     static_pages#contact

I have tried

```
root 'static_pages#home'
get '/static_pages/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
```

or

```
root 'static_pages#home'
match '/help',    :to => 'static_pages#help', via: [:get]
```

yet i still cannot solve the problem. I have been staring at this code and error for days. Please help.

*Edit to include test

```
test "should get home" do
  get root_path
  assert_response :success
  assert_select "title", "Home | #{@base_title}"
end

test "should get help" do
  get help_path
  assert_response :success
  assert_select "title", "Help | #{@base_title}"
end
```

Comment: rails -v 4.1.10; ruby -v 2.1.5p273

Comment: The first error reads `{:action=>"/", :controller=>"static_pages"}`. Notice the action (i.e. the *method* defined in the controller) is `/`. It seems your actions are named `home` and `help`. We'll be able to tell you more if you post your tests.

Comment: Are you able to go to the routes outside of the test? If you go to localhost:3000 do you get an error or does the page show up?

Comment: the page works fine, the only thing is just the test fails

Comment: Please run `rake routes` in a terminal window and add the output to your question.

Comment: I believe that syntax changed with Rails 5. If you are using Rails 4 you need to use the old syntax: `get :home` and `get :help`

Comment: yea...  after i change to :home & :help.. the problem is solved. Thanks :)